# Max3 in haskell, I'm getting errors

Tags: haskell

I'm getting a problem when I run my haskell program,

```
max3:: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
max3 a b c
          | a > b && a > c = show a
          | b > a && b > c = show b
          | c > a && c > b = show c
          | otherwise = show "At least two numbers are the same"
```

I don't know why my GHCI doesn't compile this easy code. Please it's must not be that hard.

Comment: `max3:: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> String` not `max3:: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer`.

Answer (score 3):

Your function is returning a `String`, but your type annotation indicates that it returns an `Integer`.

If you would like a `String` error message, consider using `Either`.

```
 max3:: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Either String Integer
 max3 a b c
   | a > b && a > c = Right a
   | b > a && b > c = Right b
   | c > a && c > b = Right c
   | otherwise = Left "At least two numbers are the same"
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Erik points out, your function is returning a `String`. If you want to keep the type you declared, you could have something like this:

```
max3 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
max3 a b c
      | a > b && a > c = a
      | b > a && b > c = b
      | c > a && c > b = c
      | otherwise = error "At least two numbers are the same"
```

In the `otherwise` case, calling `error` will crash your program with the given error message. You could replace the call to `error` with something more sophisticated if it doesn't suit your needs.

One possible replacement for the call to `error` would be to return the max value regardless of whether or not it's the same as other arguments:

```
      ...
      | c > a && c == b = c
      | a > c && a == b = a
      | b > a && c == b = b
      | c == a && c == b = c
```